# Trying to work with time but, typeerror: float() argument must be a string or a number

Tags: python, numpy, timestamp, stock

I have a data set that looks like this, which I have draw from IEX. The date is a timestamp as shown below after I have converted the data to array.

```
    date         close    volume
0   2020-02-03   308.66   43496401
1   2020-02-04   318.85   34154134
2   2020-02-05   321.45   29706718
3   2020-02-06   325.21   26356385

[[Timestamp('2020-02-03 00:00:00') 308.66 43496401]
[Timestamp('2020-02-04 00:00:00') 318.85 34154134]
[Timestamp('2020-02-05 00:00:00') 321.45 29706718]
[Timestamp('2020-02-06 00:00:00') 325.21 26356385]]
```

This is my code below.

```
start = datetime(2020, 2, 1)
end = datetime(2020, 2, 27)

def get_price_vol(symbol):
    get_info= get_historical_data(symbol, start, end, token='xyz',
                                  close_only=True, output_format='pandas' )
    return get_info
aapl_new = get_price_vol('aapl').reset_index()


x = np.array(aapl_new.drop(['prediction'],1))
x = x[:-forecasting_data]
print(x)
```

When I run the code below, I get this error:

```
svr_rbf = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1e3, gamma=0.1) 
svr_rbf.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

> **> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Timestamp'**

I have seen and tried other stackoverflow answers but none seem to work. I will like to keep the dates but I need to convert the timestamp away. Any inputs on this is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to keep the dates, you should convert them to UNIX Timestamps:

For this use:

```py
df.date = df.date.astype(int) / 10 ** 9
```

By the way, why do you keep dates as a variable in you model? I would not recommend to do so: you should use a dummy variable to track seasonality.

Comment: hmm.. sorry for the df.date, i will have to convert it before the function am i right? I have just edited the code, by adding the start and end date. 

and as for the dummy variable, do you have any examples? Thanks!

Comment: yes, you have to convert them before applying the SVR function. Some dummy variables can be the day of the week, the month of the year...